# Find the parent div of the Youtube iframe that just finished playing using Youtube API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, youtube-api

I have this function:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0){

        alert(event.target.parentNode);

    }
});
```

It is called every time a "state change" occurs for the embedded iframe. It only raises an alert message when the video ends, and [according to the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Events), I can get the reference to the player by calling `event.target` However, I want to be able to find the parent div of `event.target` but I am unable to call any jquery or regular javascript on it. How will I be able to find the parent div of the player that just ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**event.target** here doesn't return a HTML-element(iframe in this case), it returns the player-object. You may access the iframe using **event.target.b** (and the div by using **event.target.b.parentNode**).

Please note: this is not a part of the docs, I was inspecting the members of **event.target** by using the console. It could happen that this(the access via **event.target.b**) will change in the future.

Comment: And conversely, how would you go from the iframe HTML-element to the player-object?

Comment: It's ok. What I did was when I got the iframe from the player-object, I stored the iframe's id as the key and the player-object as the value in a global associative array. Therefore I can always call on the array to pull out the player from the iframe.

Comment: event.target does not yield player in my case. player would have had "loadVideoById" as one of the functions. Please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794974/uncaught-typeerror-object-s-has-no-method-loadvideobyid

Answer (score 17):

**event.target** is not a reliable way to go about this. As Dr. Molle warned, the event.target keys do change regularly...

There is a [getIframe()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes) function which you can work from more reliably, so `event.target.getIframe().parentNode` will give you the parent DIV.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer as it does exactly what the original question is asking for and does it in a safe way.

Comment: It was exactly my case: the iframe I could get the iframe with event.target.a, after few months with event.target.f, and so on... getIframe() is the correct answer

Comment: `target.b` does not work in 2021 anymore, but `event.target.getIframe()` still does.

Comment: [player.getIframe() in official API doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes)